# fireEvent.click is not awaiting the async functions

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

### In Jest React Test Library, when I use `fireEvent.click` I can't test the `async` functions.

#### Example Component:

```js
import {fetchSomething} from "../requests"

const myAsyncAction = async () => {
  const dataSomething = await fetchSomething();
  doSomething(dataSomething);
}
 
const handleOnClick = () => {
  myAsyncAction();
}

return <button onClick={handleOnCLick}> CLICK ME </button>
```

#### Test file:

```js
import * as Requests from "../requests"

test('should trigger some async funtion', () => {
  const spyFetchSomething = jest.spyOn(Requests, "fetchSomething").mockImplementation();
  render(<Example />);
  fireEvent.click(screen.getByRole("button"));
  expect(spyFetchSomething).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

> I've got the same result using `waitFor`

```
Expected number of calls: >= 1
Received number of calls:    0
```

```js
import * as Requests from "../requests"

test('should trigger some async funtion', async () => {
  const spyFetchSomething = jest.spyOn(Requests, "fetchSomething").mockImplementation();
  render(<Example />);
  fireEvent.click(screen.getByRole("button"));
  await waitFor(() => {
     expect(spyFetchSomething).toHaveBeenCalled()
  }); 
});
```

#### The Sandbox code: https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-napier-4qs0yx?file=/src/RawDropdown.test.tsx

This test will fail because the `fireEvent` is not waiting for the async function inside `myAsyncActio`

I appreciate any support.

Comment: `await waitFor(() => expect(spyFetchSomething).toHaveBeenCalled())`

Comment: @KonradLinkowski I've tried using the waitFor but it's not waiting for async functions when fireEvent.click trigger the event

Comment: Please show how

Comment: @KonradLinkowski I've edit the question to add this part with waitFor

Comment: @KonradLinkowski waitFor start work. Seems that my mock returned some wrong Promise and somehow it was not showing in the console. Thanks, I'll upvote your comment.

Comment: Fyi - it's best to use UserEvent instead of FireEvent as it simulates real user behavior. https://testing-library.com/docs/user-event/intro/#differences-from-fireevent

Comment: This may be an error with how jest is setup because your await test is correct. It should pass.